# Angular- change angular material datepicker format based of a format that returns from the server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In the app I want to change all my date pickers format.
After investigating, this works for me in my app.module.ts-

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But the problem is that I want that "dateInput" in my object will not be hardcoded as here "YYYY-MM-DD", but will be a value that returns from the server.

Is there a way to do it so it works in my app.module?

Thanks!

Comment: is it affordable to load this data from server before your application "runs"? this will defer the moment user sees your UI

Comment: I have no choice.. I do not know what will be that param. I expect the load to be very fast.